# PHP isset() redundant in this context?

Tags: php

I am going through the "Head First PHP & MySQL" book right now, and on many parts of the book there are code snippets used to process HTML forms. They start like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
...
}
```

The if clause is used to detect if the form has been submitted already or not. Being used to programming in C mostly, I find that construct redundant and annoying (and I also don't think it helps code readability for experienced programmers). I would rather write it as:

```
if ($_POST['submit']){
    ...
}
```

**Question**: Is there some other reason to use isset() in this context that I might be missing? Would my version of the snippet be considered non-idiomatic PHP? What about in other contexts, can you give me an example of when isset() might be useful?

Comment: `$_SERVER`? Didn't you mean `$_POST`?

Comment: @Vyktor, well spotted. Fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are situations where a variable is `NULL`, `0`, or `FALSE`. They'd fail the `if() {}` comparison, but they **are** set.

Using `isset()` also avoids a notice about an undefined variable if your error_reporting settings include `E_NOTICE`s.

Comment: The PHP Manual describes isset like this: "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL". So in this case even if the variable is set but is NULL, 0 or False you would get 0 in return right?

Comment: Yeah, I would say the main point of doing it that way is avoiding hundreds of notices in your error log that X doesn't exist.

Comment: It can be quite frustrating to have to whack `if`s all over your script to prevent the warnings when, as shown, you can evaluate its truthiness or otherwise do crazy stuff like `$var = $_POST['var'] ?: false`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page for more information about isset()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `$_SERVER` doesn't have the `submit` key, the second block would throw an `E_NOTICE` (*Undefined index*), therefore you should use `isset()` if you want to check if that key exists and is not null (or, alternatively, `array_key_exists()`, which just check for the existence).

Additionally, if you also want to check the **content** of the variable (for example, if it's set to `false` or `0`), I'd suggest to use the `!empty()` (note the negation with `!`) function instead of `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest reasons I can think of is because of PHP's [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) and [display_errors](http://php.net/display_errors) setting.

Let's say that error_reporting is set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` is turned on.

If you tried to do something like: `if ($array['iDontExist'] == false)` the code will run as expected, since the variable isn't set, it will evaluate to boolean false.  The side effect however, is that PHP will emit a notice saying the variable `$array['iDontExist']` does not exist.  The more you have this, the more likely random notices will be spammed all over the output.

I find a LOT of production systems have error reporting turned on which would result in this unwanted behavior.  If display_errors is turned off, the messages won't show up in the browser, but if error_reporting is set to track notices, the `error_log` will contain all of the notices about undefined variables, which is also an annoyance.